# Звёздочка (*) перед классом

Tags: c++

Что означает такая конструкция?

```
class Class 
{
   private:
      double* vertical;
      double* horizontal;
   public:
      static double* GetVertical() { return vertical; }
      static double* GetHorizontal() { return horizontal; }
}

void Class::SetFunction(AnotherClass & another)
{
    *Class::GetVertical() = another.mVerticalPlane;
    *Class::GetHorizontal() = another.mHorizontalPlane;
}
```

Это разыменование? Если да, то почему нужно разыменовывать сам класс, а не его экземпляр?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это скорее всего разыменование результата вызова статической функции (или функции из пространства имён, как корректно заметил в комментариях VTT, но всё же несколько странно иметь пространство имён с именем `SomeClass`). Например:

```
struct SomeClass 
{
    static int* Method();
};
```

В общем случае, возвращаться может не обычный "голый" указатель, а какой-то другой класс, имеющий перегруженный `operator*`, в частности, сюда подпадают всевозможные умные указатели или итераторы контейнерных классов.

Comment: Совсем не обязательно, например это может быть умножение на результат вызова нестатической функции или функции из пространства имен `SomeClass`.

Comment: @VTT унарный `*` это всё же разыменование, а так как у ТС второго операнда нет, то это не может быть умножением.

Comment: ТС не потрудился составить полноценный пример, соответственно перед `*` может оказаться что угодно. Например начало многострочного комментария `/*`

Comment: @VTT будем считать, что сработало некое чутьё. Законченный пример в вопросе, конечно, был бы лучшим вариантом.

Comment: да, там как раз случай с статическим методом. теперь понял, спасибо.

Comment: Почему именно статической? Такой синтаксис может вызывать нестатическую функцию базового класса из метода наследника.

Comment: @AnT предположил самый простой и очевидный вариант. Как уже указывал другой комментатор, вариантов может быть больше.

Comment: Какое еще разыменование?! `int*` - это указатель на целый тип. Его можно разыменовывать, но в том контексте это будет **оператор**, а не тип данных, как здесь.

Comment: @free_ze в вызове будет разыменование.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, вызов вернет указатель, очевидно. Никакого разыменования не будет. Разыменование (dereferencing) - это процесс **получения значения** из области памяти по адресу, например по тому, который хранится в переменной-указателе.

Comment: @free_ze `*SomeClass::Method();` нет разыменования?

Comment: @αλεχολυτб, `auto p = SomeClass::Method();` а здесь? Какой тип выведет компилятор для `p`?

Comment: @free_ze какое отношение ваш пример имеет к теме вопроса?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, зацепился глазом за ваш пример, который должен был показывать абсурдность альтернативы) Игнорируйте все написанное мной выше.

Answer (score 0):

В языке С++ постфиксные операторы и `::` всегда имеют приоритет над унарными. Поэтому никакого "разыменовывать самого класса" в вашем коде нет. Выражение

```
*Class::GetVertical()
```

группируется грамматикой языка как

```
*(Class::GetVertical())
```

то есть это применение оператора `*` к результату вызова функции `Class::GetVertical`.

Зачем автор кода в данном случае использовал квалифицированное имя функции `Class::GetVertical` вместо просто `GetVertical` - не ясно, но ошибки в этом нет.

Comment: Обновил с новым контекстом